# run external python function as vim command

Tags: python, vim

I'd like to have a directory which includes a range of vim functions written in python.

I'd like to then be able to call these functions in my .vimrc, and run them through `:<FuncName>`

I've looked at a number of resources online, and while it is quite easy to get python functionality working if it is written in your .vimrc, I'm struggling to bring in outside files.

I have the following file:

/home/daniel/vim/hey_vim.py

```
def HeyVim():
    print("Hey Vim")
```

In my .vimrc I have the following:

```
function HeyVim()

pyfile /home/daniel/vim/hey_vim.py

endfunction

:command HeyVim :call HeyVim()
```

I've also tried the following variations:

- Quoting the filepath in the vimscript function
- Removing colons from the command
- Various path expansions to get to hey_vim.py
- Quick file creation instead of print to see if it was just a printing issue
- Changing file name from hey_vim.py to HeyVim.py

When I run :HeyVim, nothing happens. There are no errors, but also nothing is printed, and no file is created when that part is in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the actual state:

- What does your Vim function? It parses your Python file.
- What does your Python file? It *defines* a new python function.

So when you run your `:HeyVim` command as you wrote it, you simply add a new Python function into the context. You could then use it like this: `:py HeyVim()`.

You should run `:pyfile` outside of the `HeyVim()` Vim function, so it runs during the Vim initialization process. Then run `:py HeyVim()` inside your Vim function, something like this:

```
pyfile /home/daniel/vim/hey_vim.py

function HeyVim()
    py HeyVim()
endfunction

command HeyVim call HeyVim()
```

Comment: It would be easier to just change the command to `command HeyVim py HeyVim()`.